# Como puedo agregar separador de miles y hasta 3 decimales en mis campos?

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo hacer para agregar separador de miles a mis campos de tipo number y que tambien tengan hasta 3 decimales?

Estos son algunos de mis campos:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="fob">Costo Fob</label>
                    <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="fob" name="fob" class="form-control" onchange="Todas();" onkeyup="Todas();" required>
                </div>

                

                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="nacFactor">Factor de Nacionalizacion</label>
                    <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="nacFactor" name="nacFactor" class="form-control" onchange="Todas();" onkeyup="Todas();"  required>
                </div>
```

Se que se puede hacer con el toLocalString pero no se como aplicarlo en una funcion para que me lo tome en mis campos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la biblioteca de javascript [autoNumeric](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) que hace justo lo que requieres con múltiples opciones de configuración. Por defecto usa como separador de miles la `,`, como separador decimal el punto `.` y usa 2 decimales. En tu caso solo necesitarías establecer la opción de 3 decimales con `decimalPlaces`.

- Para inicializar el input, instancia la clase `AutoNumeric` pasándole al constructor un selector de css que identifique el input que requieres formatear y como segundo parámetro un objeto con las opciones `new AutoNumeric('selector',{opciones});`
- Para establecer el separador de miles usa `digitGroupSeparator: ','`
- Para establecer el separador decimal usa `decimalCharacter: '.'`
- Para establecer el número de decimales usa `decimalPlaces: '3'`

Para usarla incluye el cdn en tu html e inicializa la clase en cualquier etiqueta `script` o bien en tu archivo de `javascript`. También podrías instalarla con npm. Consulta más detalles y opciones en la [documentación.](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) Ten en cuenta que debes inicializar el input de tipo `text`.

Para el procesamiento de los datos, puedes obtener el número sin formato usando el método `getNumber`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional:

```js
let myNumericInput = new AutoNumeric('.myInput',{decimalPlaces: 3});

document.querySelector('.myInput').addEventListener('keyup',() =>{
  console.log(myNumericInput.getNumber())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.5.4"></script>
 <input type="text" class="myInput">
```